# Insert special symbol (currency) into nvarchar field (with unique non-clastered index on field) T_SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I got stuck with inserting signs of currencies into nvarchar field
The field has constrained *UNQ NONCLUSTERED INDEX* properties.
Seems to me: the sings of RUB and KZT are the same?
Is there any solution to solve this issue?

```
select [utg]=unicode('₸'), [urb]=unicode('₽'),[ntg]=nchar(8376),[nrub]=nchar(8381)
```

output

| utg | urb | ntg | nrub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | 63 | ₸ | ₽ |

When trying to put symbol '₸' with an existing record of symbol '₽':
Message from SQL console is

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.glossary' with unique index 'IX_glossary_word'. The duplicate key value is (₽).
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: What collation are you using?

Comment: Note that some collations do treat some unicode characters as the *same* character for comparison operations. If you need to treat values like this as unique values, I would suggest using a binary collation (or at least on that column specifically).

Comment: You should be checking `select [utg]=unicode(N'₸'), [urb]=unicode(N'₽')` as 63 is just the question mark character

Comment: Those particular characters seem "non-weighted" in most collations. And also compare equal to empty string

Comment: I've assumed SQL Server here, by the way, however, is you are using a different product that uses T-SQL (such as Azure SQL Edge, Azure Synapse, Sybase (though the error suggests not), etc) then please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: @Martin Smith
thx, you r right, then also was trying to insert/update with N'value': with the same error

Comment: @Larnu `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`

Comment: Using MS SQL 13

Comment: Then my suspicious are correct.

Comment: @Larnu yes, changing collate settings successfully solve the issue, below I wrote about it, thx!

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, some characters are treated as the same value from a comparison point of view in some collations. For these characters, in truth you would likely be better off using `COLLATE` to change the column's definition to a binary collation. You'll need to `DROP` any constraints, etc, on the column first, but it'll look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourColumn nchar(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI CONSTRAINT UQ_YourColumn UNIQUE);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (YourColumn)
VALUES(N'₽');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (YourColumn)
VALUES(N'₸');
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP CONSTRAINT UQ_YourColumn;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn nchar(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_YourColumn UNIQUE (YourColumn);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (YourColumn)
VALUES(N'₸');
GO
SELECT YourColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: As a side note: Some characters need two `nchar` bytes, and some currencies just use two or three Latin characters, such as CHF for Swiss Francs. So `nvarchar(3)` might make more sense

Comment: Correct, @Charlieface , this is just an (overly) simplified example to demonstrate the change in behaviour between a collation like `Latin1_General_CI_AI` and a binary one.